# Xcode 8 - os_log_debug and os_log_info logs are not displayed on new Mac console (unified logging)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, logging, terminal, console

I'm trying out the new Unified Logging in Xcode 8 and Objective-C. It works fine, but it seems the logs of type `debug` and `info` are not shown on the new Mac Console. Other logs types (`error`, `fault`, `default`) are all displayed correctly.

On Xcode 8 I have:

```
os_log_t logObject = os_log_create("com.myapps", "testing log");
os_log(logObject, "Default log message."); // Captured and shown correctly
os_log_info(logObject, "Info log message."); // Not shown on Console app
os_log_debug(logObject, "Debug log message.");  // Not shown on Console app
os_log_error(logObject, "Error log message.");  // Captured and shown correctly
os_log_fault(logObject, "Fault log message.");  // Captured and shown correctly
```

On terminal I issued:

```
sudo log config --mode "persist:debug,level:debug" --subsystem com.myapps
```

And this is what I get:

[image: screenshot logs on Mac console]

Any idea about what am I missing?

NB: How can my question be considered duplicate as it was asked at least 7 month before the one of @algal?

Comment: Do you really need to configure logging system (via `sudo log config`)? To observe log stream this should work: `log stream --level debug --predicate 'subsystem == "com.myapps"'`.

Comment: @Vlad: according to Apple documentation: "debug-level messages are only captured when debug logging has been explicitly enabled via the log command-line tool or a custom logging profile". Via de `log stream` command I do see indeed all the log types, but not via the new Mac Console.

Comment: https://carpeaqua.com/2017/03/22/debug-and-info-unified-logging/

Comment: This question is not a duplicate (the other question concerns iOS, this question is about macOS). The answer for the supposedly duplicate question (use the menu items in Console.app) does not work when debugging a macOS app attached to Xcode.

Comment: If someone arrives here from Google, here's my answer: I have found no way to enable debug messages in Console.app. The only way to see them is using `log stream --level=debug --process $(pgrep my-app-name)`

Comment: You can post your own answer as an Answer instead of a comment, and set it to be the accepted answer. I spent much time looking for it...

Answer (score -2):

Info and Debug levels have to be manually enabled via the command-line or by installing a logging profile. See section **Customizing Logging Behavior While Debugging** of the [Logging documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/os/1891852-logging) for details.

Comment: that's indeed what I did with: `sudo log config --mode "persist:debug,level:debug" --subsystem com.myapps` as stated in my question. But it does not work.