# Change the log level on iOS 10 (Unified Logging) with Console.app

Tags: ios, logging, ios10

This is so simple but: how on earth do I set the level of log messages I see in Console.app, if I am trying to use iOS10's new "Unified Logging & Activity Tracing" API?

In other words, if I have code running on iOS like so:

```
fileprivate let logger = OSLog(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "mycategory")

fileprivate func logv(_ s:String) {
    os_log("%@",log:logger,type:.info,s)
}
```

Then what do I need to do to see the logged messages in Console.app? By default, only log messages of type `.error` seem to show up.

I am wondering how to do this if I am running code on a device, not in the simulator.

Related:

[Xcode 8 - os_log_debug and os_log_info logs are not displayed on new Mac console (unified logging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303711/xcode-8-os-log-debug-and-os-log-info-logs-are-not-displayed-on-new-mac-console)

Comment: Did you watch the WWDC 2016 video on this topic? Everything I know about this is what's said in that video...

Comment: I did watch it. Amazingly, I did not find anything in that video that answers this question. But I must be missing something obvious, because this is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: More questions that were not answered by the WWDC2016 video introducing this API: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/208800#208800

Comment: I don't know that you're missing anything, though. I found the video largely, shall we say, aspirational...

Comment: Do you not just use the search field? Search for the type you want, press return and change search text from searching for "Any" to searching for "Message Type"

Comment: You can then save your searches for quick reference.

Comment: @jjatie does not solve the problem that messages with log level of "info" do not seem to appear at all, which is what I'm wondering about.

Comment: @algal I figured since searching for "default" and "error" worked...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hilariously, the answer is that you just go to the Console.app's menu bar and select:

- Action / Include Info Messages
- Action / Include Debug Messages

[image]

Comment: omg, I was looking into Console.app and didn't check that menu.

Comment: One 500 bounty question here. One Apple DTS ticket. One dev forums post. One question on slack boards. And finally this. No one knew. This means something but I do not know what.

Answer (score 11):

Xcode 10.0 beta 6 (likely others too) won’t show debug messages logged from the simulator even after enabling *Include Info Messages*, *Include Debug Messages* in the Console.app. AFAIK there is no fix for this.

To see debug logs sent from the simulator you have to stream from a terminal instead:

```
xcrun simctl spawn booted log stream --debug --predicate 'subsystem == "es.com.jano.Myapp"'
```

Comment: [This article](https://www.iosdev.recipes/simulator/os_log/) suggests it is not a bug but is intended behavior, that this is because "the 'system' log level [of the Simulator] is set `info`". This suggests maybe we could workaround this if we knew how to change the system log level of iOS running in the Simulator.